# Cleaner assignment in for loop (python)

Tags: python

I have a `nodelist` object that yields a bunch of `node` objects on iteration. I need to increment these nodes based on some random condition (like `node.x > 17`). Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
for node in nodelist: 
    if node.x > 17: 
        node.x += 1
```

I can't do `map(lambda node: node.x += 1, nodelist)` because lambda can't contain assignment. I cannot do `nodelist = [node.x + 1 for node in nodelist if...]` because a `nodelist` object consists of more than just its child nodes.

Is there a way to make this shorter/cleaner?

Comment: What's wrong with it now? It seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: -1: How can assignment be "cleaner".  State change is absolutely central to procedural programming.  The assignment statement makes state change as clear as possible.  Few things can be as important as the assignment statement.  Your examples seem to make the central, critical assignment statements murky and obscure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's already pretty short and clean. Python provides some powerful tools, but sometimes simple is best; this seems like one of those times.

I also think what you have is more readable than any equivalent one-liner (that I can come up with).

---

Ok, that said, you could do this:

```
for node in (n for n in nodelist if condition):
    node.x += 1
```

That could even be compressed into one line. But I honestly prefer the way you have it now.

Comment: Aye, I'd have to agree that your for loop is the short and clean solution.  Unless you're aiming for some "smallest code" contest answer, your code is good.  If you were building a list or some such, then a list comprehension might make sense.

Comment: I prefer this approach myself.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose this "pythonic" concept has gotten to my head, and now I'm insecure about all of my python code ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually assign in a lambda:

```
import operator
map(lambda node: operator.iadd(node.x,1), nodelist)
```

respectively

```
[operator.iadd(node.x,1) for node in nodelist if ...]
```

apart from that, your code is not really bad - it is quite concise and easy to read as is.

Comment: This is shorter (in lines), but I doubt many people would find it cleaner.

Comment: I fully agree with you - I just want to point out the possibility.

Comment: This actually doesn't work if you test it (though seems like it should).  Try: `class Node(object):    pass` and then doing `nodelist = [Node(), Node()]` and then `nodelist[0].x = 19; nodelist[1].x=10;` to initialize values, then nodelist (`[node.x for node in nodelist]`) is originally `[19,10]` and after applying your code `[operator.iadd(node.x,1) for node in nodelist if node.x > 17]` it outputs [20], but looking back at nodelist its unaltered -- still [19,10].   Best to stick with the simple for loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

I vote that You are overdoing this pythonic thing :)

What is your goal: performance? I doubt You will get any.

Readability? Well, for three lines, I am not sure if functional collapse will help in this case, as it obviously will not be so obvious.

Comment: I would even go out on a limb and say that the OP's original code _is_ pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use lambda:

```
map(lambda node: node.x>17 and node.x+1 or node.x, nodelist)
```